# How to implement SXA Authentication in selected pages?

Tags: sxa, authentication

I am trying to enable login feature for selected pages in SXA site using existing header and footer components.

There is an existing header component with option like a,b,c. I need to add login feature/button along with a,b,c. can i do this with existing header component or do i have to create a new one only for selected pages?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you created the header as a partial view. That would make sense and you although not exactly stated in the question, it feels safe to assume that.

In that case you have a few options:

- Add the login feature to the header and use personalization rules to hide/show it on the pages where you need it (this does require some logic in the selection of those pages, e.g. same template).
- Create another partial view (and other page designs) - I wouldn't go for this option, but without full knowledge of your platform it is hard to determine what is best
- Add a placeholder to the partial view so you can add renderings to it. This way you can add the feature where needed (could be a good solution if you do not have many pages where it is needed)

Comment: I have created a header partial design for my site using navigation rendering and  have selected home item from tree for Start Page in Navigatin Settings. After user gets loggin in, I have to change header to have logout button in it instead of login. How can i do this? Should I need to have controller rendering for hearder?

Comment: You could put both buttons there (login and logout) and use personalization to hide them when not relevant.

Comment: I have set a folder in my site as a Start Page field for Navigation Settings section under Control Properties. Because of this, I am unable to set personalization for Login and Logout links separately. Do I need to set it for Navigation itself?

Comment: You should get the logout and login out of the navigation and display them seperately.

Comment: I added personalisation like you suggested removing Login and Logout from navigation. Now the probelm I am facing is, after login still page shows Login button. After a page refresh, it is changed to Logout. How can i fix this?

Comment: Refreshing the page after the login sounds like a good plan

Comment: That worked. You walked me through each and every step. Really that was great. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted if it helped you ;)